# Firebase causes issue "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" after delivery to itunes connect

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, admob

As you may be aware, Google starts to use Firebase as analytics so I want to use it in my current project. I succesfully finished the implementation and upload project to iTunes Connect. But I got mail below. I do not want to use push notificaiton option of Firebase but its included in SDK. Do I need to remove it?how?
Will it cause to get rejection from review?

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Instant Baby Dream". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If the library that you're using has any calls to the push notification API and you don't have a provisioning profile/certificate that enables your app to receive push notifications then you will receive this email from Apple. However if you do **not** need to use push notifications in your app then you can ignore this email.

This email doesn't mean that your app will be rejected. I used to get this email all of the time when submitting games made with Unity and using a certain Prime31 plugin for native functionality, it also made use of the push notification API which caused me to receive this email.

You can ignore it, it will be fine.

Comment: It's good answer, but not solve the problem. What can you do to disable notifications from Firebase library?

Comment: As it says in the email you receive from Apple, you should contact the author of the api to fix the issue or provide documentation on how to fix this: "If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API."

Comment: i got that warning email as well.  @Swinny89 are u sure, it will be ok if i ignore it ?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, it's just saying that you're using a framework that makes calls to the notifications api but if you're not using them then it's fine

Comment: If we wants to fix , how can we do it.

Answer (score 15):

**Solution:**

- Make sure your app does not utilize [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/);
- In your Xcode project, select the application target;
- Go to *Info* tab (alternatively, select *Info.plist* in *Project Navigator*);
- Add `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` and set it to `NO`;
- Go to *Capabilities* tab and turn ON *Push Notifications* capabilities;
- Re-generate provision profiles.

**Objective:** While this issue does not mean that your app will be rejected, the email is sent to everyone who has access to the app record on App Store Connect. For corporate team accounts this usually means that management stuff gets this "We have discovered one or more issues" email. For them it usually means that development team does something wrong. Hence, I've been asked to get rid of it.

Comment: I'm in the same boat

Answer (score 12):

If you using Firebase, but don't using firebase push notifications, to avoid this warning you should disable app delegate swizzling. Just adding FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled BOOL key with value NO to your Info.plist. And Your future release builds will be without any warnings about Push notifications.

[image: Example]

Comment: How did you come up with this? Does it break anything else, and is this the intended purpose of that key/value?

Comment: Unfortunately this key does't resolve the problem. But I think, you can try to explore problem in this direction, because if app delegate swizzling is enabled, this means that Firebase SDK will try automatically call method UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings under the hood without your action. You can find more information about swizzling at this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem happened to me as well. I added Firebase packages but did not use Push notification (Neither Apple, nor Firebase). Simply just ignored the email. It worked.