# Xcode 8 "the aps-environment entitlement is missing from the app's signature" on submit

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I've got an app that we've submitted dozens of versions to in the last 6 months and we do use APNS. I got the following email from Apple after upgrading to Xcode 8

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
> APP_NAME. Your delivery was
> successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your
> next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for
> Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement
> is missing from the app's signature. To resolve this, make sure your
> App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal.
> Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that
> includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct
> signature, and you can resubmit your app. See "Provisioning and
> Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for
> more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification
> service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future
> submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework,
> you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the
> API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
> Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

What is weird is I went to *developer.apple.com* -> *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles* and my AppId does have Push Notifications enabled still. I'm not doing anything different then I've ever done on it so am curious if the Xcode 8 update broke something. Any ideas?

BTW: The link they put for the Push Notification Programming Guide was broken in the email, so that's not a good sign.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Very easy actually. For some reason it got disabled on Xcode 8 but go to Targets -> Capabilities and verify Push Notifications is all correct on that view. For me it had a "Fix Me" I had to click, and voila.

Comment: For me, this "Fix Me" added an explicit entitlements file (something I hadn't used in years), and once I remove it, the Push Notifications capability goes disabled again. Did anyone figure out how to enable it without having to add the entitlements file?

Comment: Apple document here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_44 suggests "To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor’s Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file".

Comment: The strange thing about this problem wasn't the solution, it was the fact that on Xcode 7 this was enabled and after upgrade it got disabled.

Comment: I also had to go into the entitlements file and change the APS Environment value to 'production' because it was set to 'development' by default when created.

Comment: Finally! That's ridiculous it's been so hard to make it work. I've been removing & recreating the certs/profiles for almost 5 hours. The good thing is that I can say that I fully understand what are these certs/profiles/identifiers now :) Thank you for this hint.

Comment: @bek note that you should probably leave it as development. It gets changed to production automatically upon upload to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Does anyone know how to remove this warning? I never use Push Notifications and never have in my app but for some reason when I submit the app I get that e-mail from Apple. Why is this happening and how do I remove this issue?

Answer (score 89):

I also have the same problem, and I'm sure Push notification is off by default in Xcode8. I didn't notice it. Be careful about it.

[image: capability]

Comment: Can you tell me that why I don't have push notification section in my account ?

Answer (score 29):

There was a change in Xcode 8, where your entitlements no longer come from the App Identifiers, but from the capabilities selected in your app target. So, like Unome (the OP) said, you have to verify that Push Notifications is switched on.

For me, it wasn't a "Fix Me" button, but I had two entitlement files (one for development and one for distribution). Toggling the Push Notifications capability would add the `aps-environment` key - with the value `development` - to the development entitlements file, but it wouldn't add it to the distribution entitlements file. Copying the same key over to distribution worked to get rid of the warning email when uploading to iTunes Connect.

For most projects, it should be sufficient to toggle on Push Notifications, or if it's already on but the key isn't in the entitlements, try toggling it off and on again.

It's also worth noting that entitlements automatically get updated during archive. ie the entitlements generated for **release** builds can be different from entitlements generated for **development** builds. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1798/_index.html)

> During the app distribution process through the Xcode Organizer >
> Archives tab, entitlements are set onto the app by way of the
> provisioning profile used for code signing. It is important to be
> aware that the re-application of entitlements at this phase creates
> the opportunity for unintended entitlement differences between any
> prior development builds you may have tested. The primary purpose of
> this document is to verify that your entitlements are correct for your
> distribution builds for beta testing and App Store submission.

Comment: This is the boat I'm in, except that no matter what I specify in my `.entitlements` file for the current config/scheme, it always uses `production` as the `aps-environment`.

Comment: @AlbertBori Weird, I could only get it to show development, which was fine because when it archived, it appeared as `production`.

Comment: I did get a file with <product-name>.entitlements but it has value development for aps-environment. Where do I need to copy for distribution?

Comment: @meteors It is should be okay if the value is `development`. It will be changed in the ipa when the project is archived.

Comment: @timgcarlson This actually doesn't happen during archiving. It happens during submission or when exported. Also some useful info to check it is being set correctly here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1798/_index.html

Comment: @MarkLeonard great find. I just loaded that into the question, because comments may not get read or they can deleted...

Answer (score 26):

From the Xcode [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW78):

> Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor’s Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. (28076333)

This is a great change as it was always quite odd that the aps-environment entitlement didn't require the plist, but many others did.

For those of you that do not want to just blindly press "Fix Me" and do not currently have an entitlements file, it is just a plist file which is referenced in your project's Build Settings under "Code Signing Entitlements"

Comment: I couldn't find that quote in the linked notes!

Comment: I don't know who upvoted my comment and what was wrong, but I can find it too now.

Answer (score 13):

After a day of struggle with Xcode 8 we could not figure out why the `aps-environment` development was NOT added to our debug builds. It was missing from the entitlements section in the built app for debug testing... even though we had ENABLED the new Capability and the entitlements file existed. The issue is that the entitlements file needs to be set for ANY SDK in the Xcode Build Settings for Debug Entitlements.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between setting a value for the `Debug` key and setting it for the `Debug` > `Any SDK` one, as the latter is used to override the value for a particular SDK.

Comment: This is the solution for me

Comment: After struggling with this all morning, this was the problem I was having as well. Toggling Capabilities, generating provisioning profiles, none of it worked. This did.

Comment: this is still a valid solution in some cases on Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: I wish I could up vote this a million times. I've been struggling for a week, and this was the solution. Just typing the file path into the Code Signing Entitlements at the top wasn't enough, had to be done in the "Any SDK" part as well. This was the key to solving it for me.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same email from Apple using XCode 7.3.1.  What I did to solve the problem was:

1. Under Capabilities > Set PUSH notification ON as stated in @Bruce Tsai answer.
2. Under Build-Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity set the developer cert for debug and the distribution cert for release, as is shown in the image:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi , In Capabilities I am not getting Capabilities > Set PUSH notification

Comment: @Anuj, I added a screenshoot where it should be in your Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Automatically manage signing was off for me]

Automatically manage signing was off for me, i checked and working fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Firebase frameworks and aren't using push notifications there are two solutions 1. just put up with the 'issue' message that gets sent to your whole team every time uploading a binary. The app will still be accepted as a submission as long as you're not actually using notifications you can ignore the warning. or 2. do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46802075/7529450 . This will remove the annoying email notification and also get accepted as a submission.

Answer (score 3):

Using Xcode 9 push Notifications was enabled.

I tried disabling/re-enabling **Push Notification** capabilities. (didn't work)

I tried disabling/re-enabling **Automatically manage signing**. (didn't work)

Turns out I had to delete and re-add my provisioning profiles. ([see here how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061528/3325104))
*You might have to disable/re-enable **Automatically manage signing** after wards.*

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was because there were two entitlements files: `Entitlements-Debug.plist` and `Entitlements-Release.plist`. And only one of them (Debug) has needed settings in it.

Changing multiple value of **Build Settings > Signing > Code Signing Entitlements** to a single `MyAppName/MyAppName.entitlements` and then reenabling **Capabilities > Push Notifications** switcher did the trick for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One more option that worked: copy-pasting the source of `AppName/Entitlements-Debug.plist` into `AppName/Entitlements-Release.plist`.