# IOS 10 push notification error with cordova pushV5 plugin for ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins, ios10

I can't get push notification on ios 10 using cordova PushV5 plugin. When I'm trying to catch error, then following exception appeared (which is attached with screenshot).

no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Error screenshot:
[image]

Another screenshot which shows testing phone configuration:
[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, try looking at the Capabilities tab when you build the app, and make sure push notifications are enabled there. Even if you originally had them enabled, An Xcode update earlier this year may have disabled them. I received a notification along the same lines and this resolved things for me.

This may be the same issue:

[Xcode 8 "the aps-environment entitlement is missing from the app's signature" on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554177/xcode-8-the-aps-environment-entitlement-is-missing-from-the-apps-signature-on)