# Development team does not support the Associated Domains capability when signing code on iOs

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem when I'm trying to sign the certificate for my ionic iOs platform. The error specifies like this:

[image]

I have no idea why the error occurs since my other ionic app project using the same development team works. I've looked in the everywhere but none solved the problem. Does it have anything to do with the plugins installed on my projects?

I'm using XCode 9 beta. Here's my ionic info:
global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1 : 2.0.1
Ionic Framework          : ionic1 1.3.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9M136h 
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

Here the list plugins installed on my project:

```
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-plugin-app-preferences 0.99.3 "AppPreferences"
cordova-plugin-clipboard2 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-deeplinks 1.0.15 "Ionic Deeplink Plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, turns out the `ionic-plugin-deeplinks` caused the error. I had no idea why, I uninstalled the plugin and then the error resolved.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your email is enrolled in Apple's $99/year Developer Program.
2. When someone sends you the developer invite from Apple Developer Portal (now in iTunes Connect): https://itunesconnect.apple.com/access/users

**Make sure they check this little box for you to access certificates and profiles:** (If they did not, they can go back to the invite and add this permission anytime.)

[image]

Comment: This option will be only enabled for company account right? I am working for a client and he didn't enable that option for me so universal deep linking won't work?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, take a look into xcode and check if your signing is setup correctly. Furthermore, check under 'capabilities' if there are any actions required, in my case, I had to toggle the push option manually to add the correct entitlements.

You can also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554177/xcode-8-the-aps-environment-entitlement-is-missing-from-the-apps-signature-on/39554291) to get any further information...