# Why does itunesconnect think my app is registering for push notifications?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

Using Visual Studio 7 for Mac (ie, Xamarin) I've been publishing an iOS app to the app store for testing.  Whenever I submit I receive an alert from Apple:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Your App Name". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> **Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

I do not want to use, nor have I implemented, push notification in my app. I inherited this app from another developer, though, so I don't know it through and through.

- I've checked the App ID in the developer portal, and it has push notifications disabled.
- I've checked the entitlements.plist file in my app and it has push notifications disabled.
- I've searched my app for `registerForRemoteNotifications` and so far as I can tell I never attempt to register for push notifications.

What else do I check to make sure push notifications are off and Apple stops sending me this error message?

Comment: What are others third-party framework have you used? Because it happens sometime due to some third-party it show warning like this.

Comment: @HardikShah Firebase, SQLLitePCL, RestSharp, Newtonsoft, MaterialControls, toast.

Comment: Have you added pod for firebase messaging?

Comment: @AdamDavis Firebase...

Comment: @HardikShah I'm not using pod.  Right now I just have it reporting user engagement (app opening, etc).

Comment: @SushiHangover Looking around it appears you may be correct.  I've tried the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428539/firebase-causes-issue-missing-push-notification-entitlement-after-delivery-to and will report back if it works.  Would you please add that as an answer?

Comment: That answer didn't work.  Not sure if it's firebase.

Comment: My app is also having this issue when integrated with Firebase too.

Comment: @AdamDavis What Firebase library(s) are you using?

Comment: @SushiHangover Firebase Analytics for iOS as a Xamarin component --> https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebase-analytics

Answer (score 2):

In your info.plist, check if Remote Notification option under the Background Models tab is checked. If you don’t want to use Remote Notification, It should be unchecked.

This is your info.plist:

[image: info.plist]

There is Remote notification option.

Comment: There is no `Remote Notification` under Background Modes.  The `Enable Background Modes` box is unchecked, and there are no other boxes in that section of the plist.

Comment: I add image of info.plist. Can you check?

Comment: @PeteAlvin it is Visual Studio user interface.